# Laravel 4, how to I create seed data to tables with relationships?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I have created a database with two tables, "goals" and "partgoals". The practial use is to make a savings goal (money) and have milestones along the way (partgoals). I want the partgoals obviously be linked to a specific goal. The relationships are created but I run into trouble when trying to create my seed data.

My goal is to set up two goals table like this (GoalsTableSeeder.php):

```
<?php

class GoalsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('goals')->delete();


        $goals = array(
            array(
                'max'      => 1850000,
                'avgsav' => 3500,
                'duedate'  => date('2015-03-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'max'      => 1100000,
                'avgsav' => 5000,
                'duedate'  => date('2013-11-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            )
        );

        DB::table('goals')->insert( $goals );
    }

}
```

And my partgoals table like this (PartgoalsTableSeeder.php):

```
<?php

class PartgoalsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('partgoals')->delete();


        $partgoals = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'milestone'      => 100000,
                'duedate'  => date('2014-03-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'milestone'      => 20000,
                'duedate'  => date('2013-06-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'milestone'      => 400000,
                'duedate'  => date('2013-09-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'milestone'      => 200000,
                'duedate'  => date('2014-10-15'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            )
        );

        DB::table('partgoals')->insert( $partgoals );
    }

}
```

The migration table for "goals":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGoalsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('goals', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('max');
            $table->float('avgsav');
            $table->date('duedate');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('goals');
    }

}
```

The migration table for partgoals:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePartgoalsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('partgoals', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('id')
                ->references('id')->on('goals')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->float('milestone');
            $table->date('duedate')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('partgoals');
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Laravel (and Laravel 4).

Comment: You'd probably benefit from describing the trouble you're having. Is there a particular error message/warning? is it that your data isn't present/as expected? etc.

Comment: Sorry, I seemed abvious at first =) I get this problem in the console:[Exception]                                                                                                
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert   
  into `partgoals` (`id`, `milestone`, `duedate`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?  
  , ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) Along with the data I want to insert.

Answer (score 4):

I see a few problems with your code:

1) **The way you create the foreign key**
When assigning the Foreign key constraint, you should make that column `unsignedInteger`.
*In the code below I will correct the mistake you made of naming two columns 'id'*.

```
Schema::create('partgoals', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');        
        $table->unsignedInteger('goal_id');
        $table->foreign('goal_id')
            ->references('id')->on('goals')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->float('milestone');
        $table->date('duedate')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

2) **The way you seed your database**
If you specify a foreign key, you should declare the value when creating the entry in the table seeder. 
If you want to specify a `NULL` value, this can be done by allowing the column to accept such value (by default it doesn't). In this case, we should add `->nullable()->default(NULL)`

```
Schema::create('partgoals', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');        
        $table->unsignedInteger('goal_id')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->foreign('goal_id')
            ->references('id')->on('goals')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->float('milestone');
        $table->date('duedate')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

*Minor mistake*
3) You are passing the `'id' => 1` twice in your seeder

Comment: Where in the Laravel file structure does this file go?

Comment: @AndrewKoper `app/database/migrations`

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean by "declare the value when creating the entry", i'm also trying to seed a relational database

Comment: just use `'field' => 'value'`. The point of that part was: "foreign key has to be set if it's not nullable"

Answer (score 1):

When using `increments` in the query builder, that automatically makes that your primary key, auto-incremented, and unique.  You can't have a foreign key also be your primary key unless it's a one-to-one relationship.  That's just bad design though.  Your schema should look something like below.

```
Schema::create('partgoals', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->foreign('goal_id')
            ->references('id')->on('goals')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->float('milestone');
        $table->date('duedate')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Also, when seeding, if you use the `insertGetId` when inserting, it will return the ID of the record you just inserted.  This you can use in another insert, like inserting into another table, later.  However, this has to take place in the same script.  You may be able to pass it back out to `DatabaseSeeder` and then back into another seed script, but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, or what you're trying to do, but based on the error you added in the comments it seems that your problem is a result of trying to enter multiple records with the same primary key (1) into your `partgoals` table.

I'm not sure how you've set your tables up, but it seems like you've defined a `partgoals` table with a unique primary key column `ID`, which you're also trying to use as a foreign key to reference the `goals` table. It may be worth creating another field to hold your foreign key in the `partgoals` table.

Answer (score 0):

To seed tables with relationship, you need to defined model factories in the ModelFactory.php file and then create a seeder class to run the seeder.

For ex. ModelFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    $name = $faker->name;

    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'visible' => 1
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Video::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [
        'title' => $faker->name,
        'description' => '',
        'status' => 1
    ];
});
```

Then the seeder class can be as follows

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $categories = factory(App\Category::class, 20)->create()->each(function ($u) {
                for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
                {
                    $u->videos()->save(factory(App\Video::class)->make());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

You can refer this article on how to generate seeds for two tables with relationship http://deepdivetuts.com/seeding-two-tables-using-laravel-5-3